# JQuery and Phonegap save data from local storage in array

Tags: jquery, cordova, local-storage

I have data that stores in local storage, and I would like to pull it into array. but without success...
As you will see in the following code, I am trying to console.log the array, but it write to me:

**(Chrome console)**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input index.html:204 
>   (anonymous function) index.html:204 e.resolveWith jquery-1.6.min.js:16
>
> e.extend.ready jquery-1.6.min.js:16 c.addEventListener.z jquery-1.6.min.js:16
>
> cordova :: fired deviceready event! ripple.js:37
>
> 8 canvas not found!

**This is my local storage:**
[image]
**And this is the code:**

```
            $(function() {
                window.localStorage.setItem('Sample block', '{"time":1383107260539,"counter":5}');

                track_items_for_chart = [];

                for (i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
                    var key_name = (window.localStorage).key(i);

                    var time = (window.localStorage.getItem(key_name));
                    time = (JSON.parse(time)).time;
                    var counter = jQuery.parseJSON(window.localStorage.getItem(key_name)).counter;
                    counter = JSON.parse(counter);
                    track_items_for_chart.push("{ date: " + time + ", km: " + counter + "},");
                }
console.log(track_items_for_chart);

    });
```

Comment: the console error doesnt related to above code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the functions I wrote to convert a string to an array, add data, convert back to string then save to local storage.

```
// Converts a string from local storage to an array
// to be used by program
function convert_string_to_array (string)
{

var array = string.split("^");
return array;
}

// Converts array to string to be saved into local storage

function convert_array_to_string (array)
{

var string;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length ; i++)
{
if (string != undefined){
    string = string + "^" + array[i]; // 
 }else{
    string = array[i];
}
}

return string;
}

// Used to allow user to store a string

function add_to_array(array,welcome) // simple function to add data to array
{
array[array.length] = prompt(welcome);
}
```

Basically if you have an array of strings eg myStrings = ["Hello","hi","hey how are you"]
This will allow you to store it to localstorage for future use,
and it will be stored in the form of localStorage.myStrings = Hello^hi^hey how are you^.
Also if you expect ^ to be a common character in your data just change it to whatever you want within the functions above.

Comment: The main thing to understand is that only strings can be stored in local storage so you must convert your data from a string to an array ,then manipulate it, then convert it back to a string to be stored again.